# How to download the mind once it has been uploaded

Tags: computers, brain, immortality, mind

So, continuing along the basis of this earlier question: [Justifying why mind uploading destroys the brain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/240987/justifying-why-mind-uploading-destroys-the-brain), these aspiring immortals now have a full computer emulation of their subject’s brain. (Big thanks to you guys ;-])

They now need to download this information into a second brain. I had considered simply using the model as a blueprint with which nanites could reshape a pre-grown brain to resemble the original, but then realised that this would not destroy the computer model and so we end up with two minds: one in physical form, the other in the computer. And this is what I’m trying to avoid.

So, what method could be used to “print” the neurone-patterns of the old brain onto a new brain, which would also cause the information to be removed from the computer as it is added to the brain?

Comment: Yes interesting subject, and there are a LOT of related topics on WB about this side of the story. So please check out the search https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=download+brain  .. and attempt to make your question more specific, else this will probably be closed as a duplicate of something else. "How to" is very often put, when talking about brain uploading (or downloading.. matter of perspective..)

Comment: VTC:Opinion-Based, and I don't vote that very often. I can't see how any answer can be anything other than a raw opinion. How will you judge a best answer?  (You've been told before that we don't brainstorm. Time to start owning up to the education.)

Comment: Even glossing over the fine details, this would be at least a chapter worth of extreme justification. Any answer more complex than "one atom at a time" would be technobabble.

Answer (score 5):

I'll borrow a variant of [JamieB's answer from your other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/240989/36850).

## The Law Says So

Lawmakers (this being fiction) are reasonable and have read [the tale of MMAcevedo](https://qntm.org/lena), and thus the law is clear: only one instance of an uploaded mind may be active at any time.  If a mind is purely uploaded (the original being destroyed), it may run in one place at any given time.  If the mind is being downloaded, the uploaded version is deleted upon verification of successful instantiation in meatspace.

This is treated as effective continuity of experience, as the uploaded mind must have its execution suspended (the emulation is paused) to successfully read its momentary state and print it into the fabricated brain.  Once the brain is bootstrapped into sentience, automated EEG and direct neural stimuli confirm that the intelligence has been successfully instantiated in meatspace, and the upload is deleted.

*Addendum*: I don't believe a) that this would be the case if brain uploads were possible, and b) that even if it were, the upload would be deleted.  It would seem foolish to delete what is effectively a "save point" should something happen to your meatspace instantiation.  The whole point of digital data is simple lossless replication, so the *only* thing that could keep an uploaded brain from being run in multiple places would be if either the hardware only exists to run one brain (early stages of upload technology) or law.  And you can bet people would break that law left and right.